# No se muestran todos los label en el BottomNavigationBar. FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

En el BottomNavigationBar tengo varios BottomNavigationBarItem con sus respectivos labels pero sólo se muestra el primero, los iconos sí se muestran todos correctamente.
´´´

```
return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(55, 57, 84, 1.0),
            primaryColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                caption: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(116, 117, 152, 1.0)))),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex:_currentIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.announcement_outlined, size: 30.0), label:"ALEATORIO"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.announcement_outlined, size: 30.0), label:"MÚLTIPLE"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bubble_chart, size: 30.0), label: "IMPORTE"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bubble_chart, size: 30.0), label:"LIMPIAR"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, size: 30.0),label:"LIMPIAR TODOS"),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Supongo que no se están viendo porque al haber más de 3 items el tipo del BottomNavigationBar cambia automáticamente a shifting. Podrías especificar que el tipo se fixed aunque haya más de 3 items. `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,`. [Info](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era eso

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que no escribiste esto como respuesta sino como comentario, si la escribes como respuesta mejor porque así te la acepto :)